# AWS elastic beanstalk Node.js app is not connecting to Mongodb atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodb-atlas, aws-ebs

I am trying to connect to MongoDB atlas from elastic beanstalk using a Node.js app. on Mongo atlas, I opened the connection publicly for testing reasons (added 0.0.0.0/0 to the whitelist) and AWS security group allows all traffic.
I still can connect to MongoDB atlas from my localhost but not from AWS EBS.

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Even I have faced the same issue and it solves by restart the aws elastic beanstalk instance.

> Actually, we open do MongoClient.connect once when your app boots up
> and reuse the db object. It's not a singleton connection pool each
> .connect creates a new connection pool.

So for that purpose, we have to restart the instance and it will work but for the security purpose, we can try [VPC Peering for MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-vpc-peering-for-mongodb-atlas).

Hope this will help some one else..!!